# Use of switch with logic operators on C#

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I'm C# beginner. Why appear the error (Compiler Error CS0152, A label was repeated in a switch statement. The switch statement contains multiple cases with the value of tag '6') in "case 6:" line, when I write this code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Class1
    {
        public int abc { get; set; } 

        public Class1()
        {
            
        }

        public void mTest(int aVal)
        {
            switch(aVal)
            {
                case (2 | 4):
                {
                    break;
                }
                case 5:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                case 6:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `2 | 4` is a bit operation that is equal to `6`. You have two cases for `6` which is not allowed. If you want to test for either 2 or 4, you have to write `case 2: case 4: your_code; break;` (on multiple lines).

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, but the correct way to pattern match that condition is:

```
case 2 or 4:
    break;
```

Comment: This is a good answer, and it is not present in the other dup OPs' answers.